# php exec function on xampp work in windows but not on linux

Tags: php, linux, image-processing, xampp, exec

Few months ago I make this c++ code in Visual studio on Windows. I make .exe file from that code and everything work fine. Now I trying to do same thing on Linux so that I can put executable file on Linux web server. My linux executable file work if is called from console. But I can't run executable file over browser.
This work for me on xampp windows:

```
<?php
$imagename = $_GET['imagename'];
exec('inpainting.exe' .$imagename); 
echo "<img src=\"./images/img-uploads/ob_img$imagename.jpg\" />";
?>
```

How to run it on xampp linux? I made new execute file for linux and name of that file is just `inpainting_linux`

Comment: Using `exec()` is a bad idea.

Comment: You sure the permissions + owner is correct?

Comment: why would `inpainting.exe` run on linux? :-)

Comment: Enjoy having your server totally destroyed when someone does `http://example.com&imagename= ; rm -rf /`. You really need to STOP working on this code and learn secure coding practices first.

Comment: @David-SkyMesh: well not only that, but `inpainting.exeSomeImageName.jpg` would also need to exist & run on Linux...

Comment: What you recommend? I need to execute that inpainting file and after that show results.

Comment: on linux execute file is just *inpainting* without .exe :)

Comment: @Kenny I allows all permissions. What you mean on owner?

Answer (score 2):

You're lacking a space:

```
exec('inpainting.exe'.$imagename);  
                    ^-- here
```

meanding that given a query string of (say) `kittens.jpg`, you'll be executing:

```
inpainting.exekittens.jpg
             ^^---note lack of space
```

which is pretty much absolutely guaranteed to produce a "no such file or command" error.

And note my comment above. You're absolutely **BEGGING** to get your server destroyed or at least pwn3d remotely with this code. do **NOT** run this code on a publicly accessible server. Or better yet, take the code out back and burn it.

Comment: Well, `inpainting.exe` is not very likely to work on a Linux server even without that missing space.

Comment: assuming OP is properly building a linux executable, there's no reason a linux binary CAN'T be called something.exe. unix/linux doesn't care what the file extension is, as long as the file's got the appropriate execute bits set.

Comment: @ Marc B. - Don't be a hater. Yes, I'm beginner! What's wrong with that? One more space is not a solution. I try that few day ago.